# I want to add some functionality to my family portal for that i am designing database

Tags: database, ms-access

I would create & maintain the Directory of the entire particular Community. Each family would be able to add/update its details and would be able to link to other families too. This would be worldwide.

There must be one head who can add/update details of all family members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

msaccess is probably not the right tool for this job becuase it is mainly design for desktop application. I suggest you have a look at webtrees (https://www.webtrees.net/index.php/en/). They have a free platform that you can download and install on a web server so that everyone with internet connection can have access. It's password protected so you can control who access. If you do not have a web host you can download easyphp (http://www.easyphp.org/download.php) that you can install on your desktop to act as a virtual server. Otherwise if you search the web you should be able to get a webhost and domain name for about $40 a year.